# Adding a HDD to a Pi

Tags: peripherals, hard-drive

By looking to this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E89s2h9swIc) I am interested in some way to 'push' a HDD inside a case of RPi or at least to be mountable at the bottom/top of the case with as little wiring as possible (If possible connection over the GPIO and only external power over USB)?

The idea behind is commercial and that is why the options with less wires are better :)

PS:

I am not much of a hardware guy, so excuse me if my question sounds a little bit noobish (I still havent played with the Pi as I am getting it in the follwoing days :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no point trying to attach HDD to GPIO, since if you use USB for power anyway, it would be silly not to use data lines for data transfer.

The 2.5" HDD box is about the size of Raspberry Pi box, and can be easily fitted on the top or on the bottom, additionally glued together:

[image: the image does not belong to me, just found on the web]

Comment: The powering from the USB that I've meant was not to be plugged in the USB of a PI, but to an external adapter plugged in to the wall socket. Anyway, this seems like a fair set-up, I do believe that this is a case for HDD which turns it in to a portable USB HDD am I correct :)